# Seperation of style and logic: changing of mouse cursors

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the case where Javascript knows which elements are clickable, should Javascript be used to change the mouse cursor (by changing the css) as practically speaking the mouse cursor isn't a style property of the element in question? I am aware this is a question asking to some extend for opinions, so I am looking for an answer which covers both sides of the argument - refers to relevant expertise - and hopefully reaches a conclusion.

Just to be clear, if one would have a clickable list item for example normally one would add in Javascript

```
someLib.listen("#id li",func);
```

and in css

```
#id li{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

rather than the `someLib.listen` handling this. For example in my case I was changing the listener from a child element to the parent element and it just *seemed* to me that it does not follow the rules of separation of logic and presentation that I had to change things in two places.

Comment: The closest we can get to separating DOM changing javascript with our 'styles' is to add/remove css class names and avoid writing javascript that sets inline style

Comment: Well, if one does not consider the `cursor` change a style property then one could argue that *logically* it should be handled by javascript and nothing would be wrong with accessing `document.body.style.cursor` on a couple of mousemove listeners.

Comment: I know what you saying , but fwiw - cursor *is* defined in the css spec as a style property, so what can we do : ) - If you adapt or use ( eg jquery) style js shorthands for setting event handlers, then it is easy enough to stuff a line in to set the cursor style ( by default ) - to not have to keep setting it all the time ?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use this all the time for 'javascript' created links on non anchor elements ( divs, spans et all )

```
.jsclick { cursor:pointer }
```

Then whenever we create an event handler in js we attach this class to it ( as part of the course )

```
_elementwithhandler.className += ' jsclick';
```

Not really anything else we can do on non anchor elements. Whether to set it inline or use a class , minor point ..

I'd say use a class - easier ( for others ) to tell in future by the inspect tools which elements have been modified by js

Comment: if you expect the CSS may get decoupled from the js down the line - then adding the cursor style directly inline is probably best / best still let your js create `<a>` tags if they are to be clickable elements